# Remove extra bottom pading UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Help me please.
I don't know why the UILabel gets bottom padding, the text hasn't got any final space or break line.

[image]

This is the code on cellForItemAt:

```
    let cell:PlaceCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "place_cell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCollectionViewCell

    cell.lblTitle.attributedText = mPlace?.title?.styled(with: styleTitle!)
    cell.lblSubTitle.attributedText = mPlace?.excerpt?.styled(with: styleDescription!)
    cell.lblSubTitle.sizeToFit()
    cell.lblSubTitle.layoutEdgeInsets = .zero
```

And this is the text:

```
<p>apofkapfojqpofjqwp ofjkqpfojqwfpojfqw</p>
```

I'm using BonMot to remove te XML tags

I have already tested with ".zero" insets and "sizeToFits()"

This is storyboard where you can see the "numberOfLines" and constraints.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Make sure the numberOfLines is 0 of the Label.

Comment: Yes, the number of lines is 0

Comment: what about constraints of label?

Comment: It have 8 on top and 8 on bottom, I will edit the question to show this.

Comment: Do you want height of label based on text? or only for 2 lines

Comment: Yes, but i don't want the label bigger than text, I want that if text has 3 the label must have 3 lines. I already tried to put  "numberOfLines = 0"  and it works well.

Comment: What you have done for text based height? any code?

Comment: No, there is no code for the height of label, with constraints if must grow if necessary, and it's growing but with bottom padding

Comment: Then try to remove bottom constraints of label & add bottom layout to arrow.Of course no way you have cross check all constraints which is related to that label.Sometimes re assigning will be helpfull.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set it's constraint to what ever you want like from right, left top and bottom all you have set 10.

> There is no Matter how much line you are using in your UILabel. Matter only does for this the `bottom` constraint for the last UILabel. As i can see in the `image` which you have uploaded you have three UILabel or may be more then...

```
So here do not use the bottom constraint for the last UILabel...
```

[image: Check Image]

> And do not set height constraint to the UILabel...